# Conditional Independence (Bayesian Network)

Tags: statistics

suppose you have this bayesian network: p(a,b,c) = p(c|b) p(b|a) p(a)

a -> b -> c

are a and c conditionally independent given b?

If yes, why are they independent? How can I show that?

Comment: yes. what's the question?

Comment: why are they independent?

Answer (score 1):

Per edited question: this is super simple. One way to show it is:

$p(a,c|b) = \frac{p(a,b,c)}{p(b)} = \frac{p(a,b)}{p(b)}p(c|b) = p(a|b) p(c|b)$